# Where is the function module of container name resolve?

Tags: docker, networking

I created a bridge named `docker-br0`:

```
[root@att ~]# docker network list
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
eb92c719d431        docker-br0          bridge              local
...
```

and I now run two containers `ubuntu01` and `ubuntu02` attached in the `docker-br0`:

```
docker run -itd --name ubuntu01 --network docker-br0 ubuntu /bin/bash
docker run -itd --name ubuntu02 --network docker-br0 ubuntu /bin/bash
```

now in them they can ping each other with the **container name**:

```
root@d4b349ad46db:/# ping ubuntu01
PING ubuntu01 (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ubuntu01.docker-br0 (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms
64 bytes from ubuntu01.docker-br0 (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
```

and

```
root@3a2769dd2576:/# ping ubuntu02
PING ubuntu02 (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ubuntu02.docker-br0 (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.135 ms
```

My question is, how can a special container can not the other container's name-IP mapping?

in the `ubuntu02`(or `utbun01`) `/etc/hosts` file, it only added a IP address of its own.

```
root@d4b349ad46db:/# more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3  d4b349ad46db
```

So, where is the container name - ip resolve?

Comment: Docker runs an internal DNS service that is used by containers for resolving other container names. /etc/resolv.conf is configured to point at this DNS service.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my question.